# Black screen on phone

Tags: android, javafxports

I have problem with my 'first' application on android. When I run my program I see only black screen. I found some information and I used Android.sdk abd.exe file to check all running threads on my phone.

I run cmd and set path to android.sdk abd file. Then I executed this commend:

> adb logcat -v threadtime

After my console shows this:

```
01-14 11:54:36.798  2210  2735 D InputDispatcher: notifyMotion - action=ACTION_DOWN(0), id=0, tooltype=1, deviceId=5, source=0x1002, policyFlags=0x0, flags=0x0, metaState=0x0, buttonState=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, eventTime=1813030619000, downTime=1813030619000,
01-14 11:54:36.799  2210  2734 D InputTransport: channel 'fae6efc com.lge.launcher2/com.lge.launcher2.Launcher (server)' : action=ACTION_DOWN(0), id=0, tooltype=1, deviceId=5, source=0x1002, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, metaState=0x0, buttonState=0x0, downTime=1813030619000, eventTime=1813030619000, pointerCount=1
01-14 11:54:36.799  2210  2734 D InputTransport: channel '5c6a310 com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper (server)' : action=ACTION_DOWN(0), id=0, tooltype=1, deviceId=5, source=0x1002, flags=0x1, edgeFlags=0x0, metaState=0x0, buttonState=0x0, downTime=1813030619000, eventTime=1813030619000, pointerCount=1
01-14 11:54:36.800  3567  3567 I ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
01-14 11:54:36.847  2210  2735 D InputDispatcher: notifyMotion - action=ACTION_UP(0), id=0, tooltype=1, deviceId=5, source=0x1002, policyFlags=0x0, flags=0x0, metaState=0x0, buttonState=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, eventTime=1813079025000, downTime=1813030619000,
01-14 11:54:36.847  2210  2734 D InputTransport: channel 'fae6efc com.lge.launcher2/com.lge.launcher2.Launcher (server)' : action=ACTION_UP(0), id=0, tooltype=1, deviceId=5, source=0x1002, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, metaState=0x0, buttonState=0x0, downTime=1813030619000, eventTime=1813079025000, pointerCount=1
01-14 11:54:36.847  2210  2734 D InputTransport: channel '5c6a310 com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper (server)' : action=ACTION_UP(0), id=0, tooltype=1, deviceId=5, source=0x1002, flags=0x1, edgeFlags=0x0, metaState=0x0, buttonState=0x0, downTime=1813030619000, eventTime=1813079025000, pointerCount=1
01-14 11:54:36.849  3567  3567 I ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
01-14 11:54:36.850  2210  2940 V SoundPool: play sampleID=1, leftVolume=1.000000, rightVolume=1.000000, priority=0, loop=0, rate=1.000000
01-14 11:54:36.851  2210  2940 V SoundPool: Allocated recycled channel for same sampleID
01-14 11:54:36.851  2210  2940 V SoundPool: play channel 0xb876a680 state = 0
01-14 11:54:36.851  2210  2940 V SoundPool: SoundChannel::play 0xb876a680: sampleID=1, channelID=83, leftVolume=1.000000, rightVolume=1.000000, priority=0, loop=0, rate=1.000000
01-14 11:54:36.851  3567  3567 I Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.ordenimagesaver time:1813082
01-14 11:54:36.851   403  3522 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: getOutput() device 2, stream 1, samplingRate 0, format 0, channelMask 3, flags 0
01-14 11:54:36.851   403  3522 V APM::AudioPolicyManager:   getOutputForDevice() returns output 2
01-14 11:54:36.851  2210  2940 D AudioSystem: getIoDescriptor: ioHandle = 2, index = 0, mIoDescriptors = 0xb897f080
01-14 11:54:36.851  2210  2940 V AudioSystem: getFrameCount() output 2, frameCount 960
01-14 11:54:36.851   403  2941 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: getOutput() device 2, stream 1, samplingRate 0, format 0, channelMask 3, flags 0
01-14 11:54:36.851   403  2941 V APM::AudioPolicyManager:   getOutputForDevice() returns output 2
01-14 11:54:36.852  2210  2940 D AudioSystem: getIoDescriptor: ioHandle = 2, index = 0, mIoDescriptors = 0xb897f080
01-14 11:54:36.852  2210  2940 V AudioSystem: getSamplingRate() output 2, sampling rate 48000
01-14 11:54:36.852  2210  2940 V SoundPool: reusing track 0xb8b6b2a8 for sample 1
01-14 11:54:36.852  2210  2940 V AudioTrack: setLoop_l 0 0 0
01-14 11:54:36.852  2210  2940 D AudioTrack: start(): 0xb8b6b2a8
01-14 11:54:36.852   403   403 V AudioFlinger_Tracks: start(4096), calling pid 2210 session 13
01-14 11:54:36.852   403   403 V AudioFlinger_Tracks: ? => ACTIVE (4096) on thread 0xb7fccd88
01-14 11:54:36.852   403   403 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: startOutput() output 2, stream 1, session 13
01-14 11:54:36.852   403   403 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: startOutput() output primary->(primary)(2), stream 1, session 13
01-14 11:54:36.852   403   403 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: setBeaconMute(1) mBeaconMuteRefCount=1 mBeaconPlayingRefCount=0
01-14 11:54:36.852   403   403 V APM::AudioOutputDescriptor: changeRefCount() stream 1, count 1
01-14 11:54:36.852   403   403 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: getNewOutputDevice() selected device 2
01-14 11:54:36.852   403   403 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: setOutputDevice() device 0002 delayMs 0
01-14 11:54:36.852   403   403 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: setOutputDevice() prevDevice 0x0002
01-14 11:54:36.852   403   403 V APM::AudioPolicyEngine: getDeviceForStrategy() remove speaker device. strategy 9 ringermode 1
01-14 11:54:36.852   403   403 V APM::AudioPolicyEngine: getDeviceForStrategy() add headphone device. strategy 9 ringermode 1
01-14 11:54:36.852   403   403 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: setOutputDevice() changing device
01-14 11:54:36.852   403   403 V AudioPolicyService: AudioCommandThread() adding create patch delay 0
01-14 11:54:36.852   403   403 V AudioPolicyService: inserting command: 7 at index 0, num commands 0
01-14 11:54:36.852  2210  3556 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.ordenimagesaver/javafxports.android.FXActivity} from uid 10022 on display 0
01-14 11:54:36.855   403  1455 V AudioPolicyService: AudioCommandThread() processing create audio patch
01-14 11:54:36.855   403  1455 V AudioFlinger_Threads: sendConfigEvent_l() num events 1 event 3
01-14 11:54:36.856   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Threads: thread 0xb17b1008 type 0 TID 1625 waking up
01-14 11:54:36.856   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Threads: processConfigEvents_l() remaining events 1
01-14 11:54:36.856   403  1625 D audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(0: deep-buffer-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
01-14 11:54:36.856   403  1625 V audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: exit: code(0)
01-14 11:54:36.856   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Threads: processConfigEvents_l() DONE thread 0xb17b1008
01-14 11:54:36.857   403  1455 V AudioPolicyService: -AudioCommandThread 7
01-14 11:54:36.857   403  1455 V AudioPolicyService: AudioCommandThread() going to sleep
01-14 11:54:36.857   403   403 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: setOutputDevice() createAudioPatch returned 0 patchHandle 103num_sources 1 num_sinks 1
01-14 11:54:36.857   403   403 V AudioPolicyService: AudioCommandThread() adding update audio patch list
01-14 11:54:36.857   403   403 V AudioPolicyService: inserting command: 10 at index 0, num commands 0
01-14 11:54:36.857   403   403 V AudioPolicyService: AudioCommandThread() adding set voice volume volume 0.571429, delayMs 0
01-14 11:54:36.857   403   403 V AudioPolicyService: inserting command: 4 at index 0, num commands 0
01-14 11:54:36.857   403  1455 V AudioPolicyService: AudioCommandThread() processing set voice volume volume 0.571429
01-14 11:54:36.857   403  1455 V AudioPolicyService: -AudioCommandThread 4
01-14 11:54:36.857   403  1455 V AudioPolicyService: AudioCommandThread() going to sleep
01-14 11:54:36.857   403   403 V AudioPolicyService: AudioCommandThread() adding set parameter string fm_volume=0.1115583479, io 2 ,delay 0
01-14 11:54:36.857   403   403 V AudioPolicyService: inserting command: 3 at index 0, num commands 0
01-14 11:54:36.857   403  1455 V AudioPolicyService: AudioCommandThread() processing set parameters string fm_volume=0.1115583479, io 2
01-14 11:54:36.857   403  1455 V AudioFlinger: setParameters(): io 2, keyvalue fm_volume=0.1115583479, calling pid 403
01-14 11:54:36.857   403  1455 V AudioFlinger_Threads: ThreadBase::setParameters() fm_volume=0.1115583479
01-14 11:54:36.857   403  1455 V AudioFlinger_Threads: sendConfigEvent_l() num events 1 event 2
01-14 11:54:36.858   403  1456 V AudioPolicyService: AudioCommandThread() processing update audio patch list
01-14 11:54:36.858   403  1456 V AudioPolicyService: -AudioCommandThread 10
01-14 11:54:36.858   403  1456 V AudioPolicyService: AudioCommandThread() going to sleep
01-14 11:54:36.858  2210  3556 D ActivityManager: setTaskToReturnTo : TaskRecord{dd1e57 #73 A=com.ordenimagesaver U=0 sz=4} / mTaskToReturnTo = 1
01-14 11:54:36.862  2210  3556 D InputDispatcher: Focus left window: Window{fae6efc u0 com.lge.launcher2/com.lge.launcher2.Launcher}
01-14 11:54:36.866   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Threads: processConfigEvents_l() remaining events 1
01-14 11:54:36.866   403  1625 D audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(0: deep-buffer-playback) kvpairs: fm_volume=0.1115583479
01-14 11:54:36.866   403  1625 D audio_hw_fm: audio_extn_fm_set_parameters: set_fm_volume usecase
01-14 11:54:36.866   403  1625 D audio_hw_fm: fm_set_volume: (0.111558)
01-14 11:54:36.866   403  1625 E audio_hw_fm: fm_set_volume: FM not active, ignoring set_fm_volume call or mute state 0
01-14 11:54:36.866   403  1625 V audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: exit: code(0)
01-14 11:54:36.866   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Threads: processConfigEvents_l() DONE thread 0xb17b1008
01-14 11:54:36.866   403  1455 V AudioPolicyService: -AudioCommandThread 3
01-14 11:54:36.866   403  1455 V AudioPolicyService: AudioCommandThread() going to sleep
01-14 11:54:36.866   403   403 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: checkAndSetVolume() cannot set stream 6 volume with force use = 0 for comm
01-14 11:54:36.866   403   403 V AudioFlinger_Threads: signal playback thread
01-14 11:54:36.868  2210  2940 V SoundPool: delete oldTrack 0x0
01-14 11:54:36.869  2210  3556 D AppWindowTokenEx: AppWindowTokenEx init..
01-14 11:54:36.874  3567  3567 I [LGHome]EVENT: [Launcher.java:5515:onWindowFocusChanged()]onWindowFocusChanged() hasFocus false
01-14 11:54:36.874  3567  3567 I [LGHome]EVENT: [Launcher.java:5541:setEnableShakeHandlers()]disableShakeHandlers
01-14 11:54:36.874  3567  3567 I [LGHome]EVENT: onPause
01-14 11:54:36.877   403  1625 D audio_hw_primary: start_output_stream: enter: stream(0xb7f5d7d8)usecase(0: deep-buffer-playback) devices(0x2)
01-14 11:54:36.877   403  1625 D audio_hw_primary: select_devices: enter and usecase(0)
01-14 11:54:36.877   403  1625 D msm8974_platform_lge: LGE_platform_get_output_snd_device: enter(0:2)
01-14 11:54:36.877   403  1625 V msm8916_platform: platform_get_output_snd_device: enter: output devices(0x2)
01-14 11:54:36.877   403  1625 V msm8916_platform: platform_get_output_snd_device: exit: snd_device(speaker)
01-14 11:54:36.877   403  1625 V platform_apt: lge_get_output_in_mandatory_depth: enter and devices(2)
01-14 11:54:36.877   403  1625 D msm8974_platform_lge: LGE_platform_get_output_snd_device: exit: out_snd_device(speaker)
01-14 11:54:36.877   403  1625 D audio_hw_primary: select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
01-14 11:54:36.877   403  1625 D audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: enter  2
01-14 11:54:36.877   403  1625 D hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
01-14 11:54:36.877   403  1625 D audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
01-14 11:54:36.883   403  1625 W audio_hw_utils: audio_extn_utils_update_stream_app_type_cfg: App type could not be selected. Falling back to default
01-14 11:54:36.883   403  1625 I audio_hw_primary: select_devices Selected apptype: 69936
01-14 11:54:36.883   403  1625 V audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: enter: usecase(0)
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 E audio_hw_dolby: audio_extn_dolby_ds2_set_endpoint: Dolby set endpint :0x2
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 V msm8916_platform: platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(14)
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audio_cal, acdb_id = 14, path =  0
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_asm_topology
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_STREAM_TOPOLOGY_ID
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_adm_topology
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TOPOLOGY_ID
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audtable
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TABLE
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AUDPROC_CAL
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audvoltable
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_GAIN_DEP_STEP_TABLE
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AUDPROC_VOL_CAL
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_afe_cal
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_COMMON_TABLE
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AFE_CAL
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_hw_delay : acdb_id = 14 path = 0
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_AVSYNC_INFO: ACDB_CMD_GET_DEVICE_PROPERTY
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 I audio_hw_utils: audio_extn_utils_send_app_type_cfg app_type 69936, acdb_dev_id 14, sample_rate 48000
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 V msm8974_platform_lge: LGE_platform_add_backend_name: enter: 2
01-14 11:54:36.884   403  1625 D audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: apply mixer and update path: deep-buffer-playback
01-14 11:54:36.885   403  1625 V audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: exit
01-14 11:54:36.885   403  1625 D audio_hw_primary: select_devices: done
01-14 11:54:36.885   403  1625 V audio_hw_primary: start_output_stream: Opening PCM device card_id(0) device_id(0) format(0)
01-14 11:54:36.888   403  1625 V audio_hw_primary: start_output_stream: pcm_prepare
01-14 11:54:36.895 11337 11337 I System.out: usetextureview = false, useswipekeyboard = false
01-14 11:54:36.895 11337 11337 V FXActivity: onCreate called, using 8.60.7-SNAPSHOT
01-14 11:54:36.896 11337 11585 V FXActivity native: Notification queue started
01-14 11:54:36.902 11337 11337 V FXActivity native: appDataDir: /data/user/0/com.ordenimagesaver
01-14 11:54:36.903 11337 11337 V FXActivity: onStart
01-14 11:54:36.903 11337 11337 V FXActivity: onResume
01-14 11:54:36.907   403  1625 D AudioFlinger_Threads: mixer(0xb17b1008) throttle end: throttle time(30)
01-14 11:54:36.908 11337 11337 D PhoneWindow: notifyNavigationBarColor, color=0x: ff000000, token: android.view.ViewRootImplAO$WEx@ab25162
01-14 11:54:36.909  2210  3521 D WindowManager: notifyNavigationBarColor(), token: android.os.BinderProxy@84a02b6, color: ff000000
01-14 11:54:36.918   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Threads: mixer(0xb17b1008) throttle begin: ret(3840) deltaMs(0) requires sleep 10 ms
01-14 11:54:36.919  2210  2339 I SystemUI[Framework]: PhoneWindowManager.updateSystemUiVisibilityLw() :visibility=0x8600, pkg=com.ordenimagesaver
01-14 11:54:36.920  2210  3044 D InputDispatcher: Focus entered window: Window{31acbb7 u0 com.ordenimagesaver/javafxports.android.FXActivity}
01-14 11:54:36.921  2210  2339 W WindowManager: Call!!!getLGSystemUiVisibility. =0x0
01-14 11:54:36.921  2210  2339 D StatusBarManagerServiceEx: setLGSystemUiVisibility(0x0)
01-14 11:54:36.921  2210  2339 D StatusBarManagerServiceEx: manageNaviBtnDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{31acbb7 u0 com.ordenimagesaver/javafxports.android.FXActivity}
01-14 11:54:36.921  2210  2339 I SystemUI[Framework]: ==>disabledNaviBtn() what=0x0, token=android.os.Binder@bb24803,  pkg=Window{31acbb7 u0 com.ordenimagesaver/javafxports.android.FXActivity}
01-14 11:54:36.921  2210  2339 I SystemUI[Framework]: disableNaviBtn: mDisabledNaviBtn=0x0,  mDisableRecords.size=0
01-14 11:54:36.921  2210  2339 D PhoneWindowManagerEx: [PWM]1.notifyNavigationBarColor => mLastColorNavigationBar=0xff000000
01-14 11:54:36.922  3026  3026 I NavigationThemeResource: notify navigation bar color(0xff000000)
01-14 11:54:36.922  3026  3026 I NavigationThemeResource: NavigationKey Color is changed(WHITE_WITH_SHADOW -> WHITE)
01-14 11:54:36.922  3026  3026 I NavigationThemeResource:  BarMode=4, Theme=BLACK, LightBackground=false (NOT Transparent)
01-14 11:54:36.922  3026  3026 I NavigationThemeResource: , Keyguard show=false, IME shown=false, Bar vertical=false, Panel expanded=false
01-14 11:54:36.937 11337 11337 V FXEntity: Surface created.
01-14 11:54:36.938 11337 11337 V FXActivity native: [JVDBG] SURFACE created native android window at 0xb798f7c8, surface = 0xbe837b00
01-14 11:54:36.938   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Threads: track(0xb7fccd88) underrun,  framesReady(0) < framesDesired(962)
01-14 11:54:36.938   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Tracks: presentationComplete() mPresentationCompleteFrames 0 framesWritten 3840
01-14 11:54:36.938   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Tracks: presentationComplete() reset: mPresentationCompleteFrames 7680 audioHalFrames 3840
01-14 11:54:36.939 11337 11337 I GLASS   : Native code is notified that surface has changed (repaintall)!
01-14 11:54:36.940 11337 11337 V FXEntity: Called Surface changed [480, 749], format 4
01-14 11:54:36.940 11337 11337 V FXActivity native: [JVDBG] SURFACE created native android window at 0xb798f7c8, surface = 0xbe837ae0
01-14 11:54:36.941 11337 11337 I GLASS   : Native code is notified that surface has changed with size provided (repaintall)!
01-14 11:54:36.941 11337 11337 V FXEntity: Called Surface redraw needed
01-14 11:54:36.941 11337 11337 V FXEntity: Redraw...
01-14 11:54:36.941 11337 11337 I GLASS   : Call surfaceRedrawNeeded
01-14 11:54:36.941 11337 11337 I GLASS   : Native code is notified that surface needs to be redrawn (repaintall)!
01-14 11:54:36.941 11337 11337 V FXEntity: Wait a while before doing this again...
01-14 11:54:36.943  2210  8114 V SoundPool: process 0xb876a680 channel 83 event BUFFER_END
01-14 11:54:36.943  2210  3309 V SoundPool: awake
01-14 11:54:36.943  2210  3309 V SoundPool: Getting channel from stop list
01-14 11:54:36.943  2210  3309 V SoundPool: stop
01-14 11:54:36.943  2210  3309 D AudioTrack: stop(): 0xb8b6b2a8
01-14 11:54:36.943   403  1635 V AudioFlinger_Tracks: stop(4096), calling pid 2210
01-14 11:54:36.943   403  1635 V AudioFlinger_Tracks: not stopping/stopped => stopping/stopped (4096) on thread 0xb17b1008
01-14 11:54:36.944  2210  3309 V SoundPool: done_l(83)
01-14 11:54:36.944  2210  3309 V SoundPool: move to front
01-14 11:54:36.949   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Tracks: presentationComplete() mPresentationCompleteFrames 7680 framesWritten 3840
01-14 11:54:36.949   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Tracks: presentationComplete() mPresentationCompleteFrames 7680 framesWritten 4800
01-14 11:54:36.959   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Tracks: presentationComplete() mPresentationCompleteFrames 7680 framesWritten 4800
01-14 11:54:36.959   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Tracks: presentationComplete() mPresentationCompleteFrames 7680 framesWritten 5760
01-14 11:54:36.969   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Tracks: presentationComplete() mPresentationCompleteFrames 7680 framesWritten 5760
01-14 11:54:36.969   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Tracks: presentationComplete() mPresentationCompleteFrames 7680 framesWritten 6720
01-14 11:54:36.979   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Tracks: presentationComplete() mPresentationCompleteFrames 7680 framesWritten 6720
01-14 11:54:36.979   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Tracks: presentationComplete() mPresentationCompleteFrames 7680 framesWritten 7680
01-14 11:54:36.979   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Threads: removeTracks_l removing track on session 13
01-14 11:54:36.990   403  1625 V AudioPolicyService: AudioCommandThread() adding stop output 2
01-14 11:54:36.990   403  1625 V AudioPolicyService: inserting command: 5 at index 0, num commands 0
01-14 11:54:36.990   403  1456 V AudioPolicyService: AudioCommandThread() processing stop output 2
01-14 11:54:36.990   403  1456 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: stopOutput() output 2, stream 1, session 13
01-14 11:54:36.990   403  1456 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: setBeaconMute(1) mBeaconMuteRefCount=0 mBeaconPlayingRefCount=0
01-14 11:54:36.990   403  1456 V APM::AudioOutputDescriptor: changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
01-14 11:54:36.990   403  1456 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0
01-14 11:54:36.990   403  1456 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: setOutputDevice() device 0000 delayMs 160
01-14 11:54:36.990   403  1456 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: setOutputDevice() prevDevice 0x0002
01-14 11:54:36.990   403  1456 V APM::AudioPolicyEngine: getDeviceForStrategy() remove speaker device. strategy 9 ringermode 1
01-14 11:54:36.990   403  1456 V APM::AudioPolicyEngine: getDeviceForStrategy() add headphone device. strategy 9 ringermode 1
01-14 11:54:36.990   403  1456 V APM::AudioPolicyManager: setOutputDevice() setting same device 0x0000 or null device
01-14 11:54:36.990   403  1456 V AudioPolicyService: -AudioCommandThread 5
01-14 11:54:36.990   403  1456 V AudioPolicyService: AudioCommandThread() going to sleep
01-14 11:54:37.141 11337 11337 V FXEntity: Redraw again...
01-14 11:54:37.142 11337 11337 I GLASS   : Call surfaceRedrawNeeded
01-14 11:54:37.142 11337 11337 I GLASS   : Native code is notified that surface needs to be redrawn (repaintall)!
01-14 11:54:37.152 11337 11337 V FXEntity: Called Surface redraw needed
01-14 11:54:37.152 11337 11337 V FXEntity: Redraw...
01-14 11:54:37.152 11337 11337 I GLASS   : Call surfaceRedrawNeeded
01-14 11:54:37.152 11337 11337 I GLASS   : Native code is notified that surface needs to be redrawn (repaintall)!
01-14 11:54:37.152 11337 11337 V FXEntity: Wait a while before doing this again...
01-14 11:54:37.352 11337 11337 V FXEntity: Redraw again...
01-14 11:54:37.352 11337 11337 I GLASS   : Call surfaceRedrawNeeded
01-14 11:54:37.352 11337 11337 I GLASS   : Native code is notified that surface needs to be redrawn (repaintall)!
01-14 11:54:37.369  2210  2419 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.ordenimagesaver/javafxports.android.FXActivity: +487ms
01-14 11:54:37.384 11337 11337 V ViewRootImpl: Contents drawing finished : com.ordenimagesaver/javafxports.android.FXActivity
01-14 11:54:37.385 11337 11337 I Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@158b82d time:1813617
01-14 11:54:37.391  3567  3788 E Surface : getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb898a880
01-14 11:54:37.780  3567  3567 I [LGHome]EVENT: onStop
01-14 11:54:37.795  2210  2337 I ProcessStatsService: Prepared write state in 14ms
01-14 11:54:39.934   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Threads: Audio hardware entering standby, mixer 0xb17b1008, suspend count 0
01-14 11:54:39.934   403  1625 D audio_hw_primary: out_standby: enter: stream (0xb7f5d7d8) usecase(0: deep-buffer-playback)
01-14 11:54:40.121   403  1625 V audio_hw_primary: stop_output_stream: enter: usecase(0: deep-buffer-playback)
01-14 11:54:40.121   403  1625 V audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: enter: usecase(0)
01-14 11:54:40.121   403  1625 V msm8974_platform_lge: LGE_platform_add_backend_name: enter: 2
01-14 11:54:40.121   403  1625 D audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: deep-buffer-playback
01-14 11:54:40.121   403  1625 V audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: exit
01-14 11:54:40.121   403  1625 D audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: enter 2
01-14 11:54:40.121   403  1625 D hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
01-14 11:54:40.121   403  1625 D audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
01-14 11:54:40.123   403  1625 V audio_hw_primary: stop_output_stream: exit: status(0)
01-14 11:54:40.123   403  1625 V audio_hw_primary: out_standby: exit
01-14 11:54:40.123   403  1625 V AudioFlinger_Threads: thread 0xb17b1008 type 0 TID 1625 going to sleep
01-14 11:54:41.259   415   508 I ThermalEngine: Sensor:pa_therm0:27000 mC
```

I do not see any exceptions and still I have black screen when I run my program on smartphone with Android OS.

Comment: Could we see your code?

Comment: The stacktrace is clear: `ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ordenimagesaver.OrdenImageSaver"`. Is this your main class? Have you renamed it? The AndroidManifest.xml file needs the actual main class.
                    `

Comment: Your main class in the build file says `com.orden.OrdenImageSaver`, so I'll ask again: did you rename the package? Check AndroidManifest.xml and make sure the package there doesn't say `com.ordenimagesaver.OrdenImageSaver`

Comment: Ehh..  Only what I need is a possibility to create simple application with sqlite db. Thats all. I know something about JavaFX and this is interesting thing.

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: See the manifest: the package and the main.class parameter don't match your main class package. Fix the manifest and deploy again

Comment: I changed. They match and still does not work.

Comment: Can you update the error you get now?

Comment: Yes this is my last Log from windows cmd. I don't see any exceptions, but application still does not work.

Comment: I found problem. My application did not write FXML document. When I declared all controls in script then all run good.

Answer (score 0):

`The ClassNotFoundException` says it can't find the `OrdenImageSaver` class. It sounds like you're trying to load an image and since that class can't be found, the screen is just displaying black.

Make sure the class is located in the `com.ordenimagesaver` package. After that, try the following:

Clear app `cache`

Clear app `data`

`Uninstall` app

`Restart` Android Studio

`Run/Debug` again